# Cordova (2.1.0) PlugIn does not work

Tags: cordova, plugins

i have a problem with a cordova (v 2.1.0) PlugIn.

```
package com.phonegap.plugins.video;


import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;

public class Test222 extends Plugin {

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {

        Log.d("asd", "execute");
        PluginResult.Status status = PluginResult.Status.OK;
        return new PluginResult(status, "");
    }
}
```

config.xml

```
<plugin name="Test222" value="com.phonegap.plugins.video.Test222"/>
```

JS code:

```
function init() 
{
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",initTracking,false);
}

function initTracking() 
{
    cordova.exec(onTrackingDataResult,onTrackingDataFail,"Test222","initTracking",null);
}
```

The execute method is never called (breakpoint) and my onTrackingDataFail callback function is called with status 8 = JSON Error.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: solved it.
last param in js call must be an array.
this works

    cordova.exec(onTrackingDataResult,onTrackingDataFail,"Test222","initTracking",[null]);

Comment: Cool , i was sending a JSON object in cordova.exec and did not pay attention to the JSON array thing.Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

i'm develop plugin in cordova , and i have this structure in the method normally
 
 
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) 
    { 
        callbackContext.success("Hello world") 
        return true; 
    } 
 
Concept.. 
callbackContext.success ----  return to side of JAvascript to a sumon the  
meothod  success

JavaScript....... 
 
function  success(msn){
  alert(msn); // Hello world 
 
} 
 
somthing  llike this, try in yout code.